# How to give an input stimulus to the DUT in a testbench when we have a 10-bit input?

Tags: fpga, verilog, simulation, quartus, testbench

How do you get around this problem?

I am spending a lot of time in giving a 10-bit input all the way from 1111111111 to 0000000000.

How do I effectively write loops in my testbench when I am giving an input stimulus?

```
module testbench();

reg [9:0] SW;
wire [9:0] LEDR;
wire [6:0]  HEXO;

EXERCISE2 instanc (.SW(SW), .LEDR(LEDR), .HEX0(HEX0));

initial 
begin 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 


SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = ;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 

SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 0;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 0;SW[5] = 1;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 0;SW[3] = 1;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 0;SW[1] = 1;SW[0] = 1; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 0; 

#10 
SW[9] = 0; SW[8] = 0;SW[7] = 1;SW[6] = 1;SW[5] = 0;SW[4] = 1;SW[3] = 0;SW[2] = 1;SW[1] = 0;SW[0] = 1;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to effectively use loops in your code?

Comment: Did you plan to write 1024 lines of code, one for each case?

Comment: Yes i am asking how to effectively write loops in my testbench when i am giving an input stimulus.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop here. A more idiomatic way (well, it might be opinionated, but it is one step closer to a synthesizable test, if you plan one) would be an `always` block such as:

```
module test;

  reg [9:0] SW;
  
  initial 
      SW <= 10'b1111111111;

  always begin 
    #10 SW <= SW - 1'b1;
    $display("%h", SW);
    if (SW==10'b0) $finish; // End the simulation once reached the final value
  end

endmodule
```

[Demo](https://edaplayground.com/x/CUWR)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to assign the `SW` input to a fixed number of increasing values:

```
module testbench();

reg [9:0] SW;
wire [9:0] LEDR;
wire [6:0]  HEXO;

EXERCISE2 instanc (.SW(SW), .LEDR(LEDR), .HEX0(HEX0));

integer i;
initial begin
    for (i=0; i<20; i=i+1) begin
        SW = i;
        #10;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Change `20` to whatever you want.

Also, as shown, there is no need for you to make assignments to individual bits of the `SW` bus (`SW[9]`, `SW[8]`, etc.).  Assigning to the full bus signal is a lot less code, which means it's a lot less error prone.

Use this for decreasing values:

```
for (i=20; i>0; i=i-1) begin
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.7.1 *The for-loop*.